# How to view the rendered (raw) query from a MySQLi prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm building a logging class for my PHP/MySQLi app.  I can obviously log the raw prepared statement (with question marks), but without manually parsing it, is there anyway to see the actual raw query executed in MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on query logging in MySQL and monitor the mysql query log file.

In your my.cnf or my.ini file in the `mysqld` section add a directive:

```
log = /path/to/my/log/file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to see the 'raw' queries, port sniffing using tcpdump, mysql-proxy, or watch 'mysqladmin -ppasswd "processlist"' though for a short time you can do this:

```
Start:
echo "set global general_log_file=mysqllogfile;set global general_log=1;" | mysql -u root -ppasswd

From now on all queries will appear in /var/lib/mysql/mysqllogfile

Stop:
echo "set global general_log=0;" | mysql -u root -ppasswd
```

Don't forget to disable when finished!

You can log the queries to the table mysql.general_log:

```
echo "set global log_output=TABLE;" | mysql -u root -ppasswd
# restart logging
echo "set global general_log=0;" | mysql -u root -ppasswd
echo "set global general_log=1;" | mysql -u root -ppasswd
```

Note that viewing the general_log table also causes them to be updated!

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to do it WITHIN PHP.  Is this possible with MySQLi?  Thanks!

Comment: You can issue these commands and retrieve logged queries from table mysql.general_log with php-mysqli too, but why? If you write and prepare the queries properly, then the raw sql is predictable. You could always prepare queries with your own class or sprintf with %d and '%s' with mysqli_real_escape_string() for all parameters to make prepared 'raw' sql and then log those, but as far as I know, the only way of seeing what the mysql server sees using php-mysqli prepared statements is to query the general_log, and for only a short time-window.